# How to revert a shrink of an LVM volume

Tags: linux, partition, lvm

I had a Linux LVM volume that was about 400 GB.
I shrank it to 217 GB following the steps below.

```
umount /local
e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/vg00-lvol2
resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg00-lvol2 217G
lvresize -L 217G /dev/mapper/vg00-lvol2
lvdisplay /dev/mapper/vg00-lvol2
mount /local
```

And then I resized the physical volume to 260 GB with `pvresize`. If I do `pvdisplay` and `lvdisplay` now, I get:

```
lvm> pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda3
  VG Name               vg00
  PV Size               260.00 GB / not usable 31.81 MB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size (KByte)       32768
  Total PE              8319
  Free PE               250
  Allocated PE          8069
  PV UUID               6itmL0-3HAd-tmhA-a3u3-ketO-H7OO-MahFc7

lvm> lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/vg00/lvol1
  VG Name                vg00
  LV UUID                JFATdC-lqxK-wsBc-VgL1-33Xv-PUfb-Y28fk2
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                35.16 GB
  Current LE             1125
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/vg00/lvol2
  VG Name                vg00
  LV UUID                F81eoe-xokM-Jqwr-NXND-VujX-BwN6-Kh0zZa
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                217.00 GB
  Current LE             6944
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:1
```

How can I revert these steps? That is, to resize the physical volume and the logical volume back to their original sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest that you reverse the sequence:

```
 pvresize
 lvresize
 resize2fs
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Does `vgresize` revert the `pvresize`? `vg` commands are for volumes groups, `pg` for physical volumes, aren't they?

Comment: changed to pvresize

Comment: Efectiviwonder, following the steps below did the trick beautifully:
`pvresize /dev/sda3`, `lvresize -l +100%FREE /dev/sda3`, `umount /local`, `e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/vg00-lvol2`, `resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg00-lvol2`, `mount /local`